# Matlab on Windows: Change 'mex' default compiler to Cygwin's GCC

Tags: matlab, mex

I installed Matlab on my Windows 7 machine and I also have MSVC 2012 and Cygwin.

I am trying to compile some library using MEX in Cygwin using Makefile, but for some reason, MEX always tries to use `Visual C++ 2012` instead of my `gcc`.

How can I tell MEX to use `gcc` instead?

Comment: Which version of MATLAB is this? Make sure you are only trying to set a compiler that is supported by **your** MATLAB version. [Here's a list of supported compilers for R2015b](http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2015b/index.html).

Comment: 2014a or 2014b, I am not sure. The GCC is from the latest Cygwin version

Answer (score 0):

Type `mex -setup` into the Command Window and follow the instructions to select your choice of compiler.

Comment: I tried it - didn't find any option that finally leads to changing the compiler

Comment: @SomethingSomething Check this page for compatibility. http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2013b/index.html?sec=glnxa64